# ¿Solucionar retraso en AdViews?

Tags: java, android-studio, xml

implemento adviews en Android Studio pero en versiones 8.0> se relentiza mucho la aplicacion y no deberia, dejo el codigo de mi activity final. aunque no es solo en este activity si no en todos los que implemento android studio

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;


public class FinishActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ImageButton btn;
    public AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_finish);

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_regresar);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                }
        });
    }

    @Override

    public void onBackPressed(){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Este es el XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FinishActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="388dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_ingame" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="179dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_ingame" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="91dp"
        android:text="Proximamente implementaremos mas niveles"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="50dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="432dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="308dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="¡Has culminado todos los niveles!"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_regresar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/home" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_regresar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="237dp"
        android:text="Regresar" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La carga de anuncios no debería provocar tu aplicación se ralentiza, lo que sucede es que estas cargando una misma Activity varias veces.

En el caso de MainActivity que seguramente es tu Activity principal y la cual abre FinishActivity, la puedes mantener abierta, en cambio desde `FinishActivity` no inicies nuevamente `MainActivity` mediante un `Intent`, solo termina la activity usando el método `finish()` para que destruya `FinishActivity` y regreses nuevamente a MainActivity:

```
public class FinishActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ImageButton btn;
    public AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_finish);

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_regresar);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                   finish();
                }
        });
    }

    @Override

    public void onBackPressed(){
        //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuestas, lo he intentado pero no es la solucion, cuando lanzo una activity con un intent que no tiene admob va super rapido, pero cuando voya  lanzar una que tiene admob es como si se relentizara.